# which python 2.7.9 file is the correct file for intell proc tessor

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I want to work with scrapy, and the scrapy website suggested to install python 2.7

i went to python website and i saw that the last version of python 2.7 is python 2.7.9

i clicked download and i found this page

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-279/

i am using windows 64 bit, so i thought that `Windows x86-64 MSI installer` is the one that i should use, but then i checked that it is not for intell processor.

could you help me please and tell me which file should i install?

many thanks

Comment: there is nothing in 2.7.9 that would be incompatible with any other 2.7.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x86-64 msi binary is designed for all Windows 64-bit installations.

If your computer is running Windows 64 bit, then install the x86-64 msi.

Comment: is it the best option for my case ? (windows 7 64 bit), to work with scrapy, which suggested 2.7 not 2.7.9

Comment: what file did you mean by `install the x86-46 msi` please?

Comment: could you check my comments please? i am in hurry, plus one